# How to install Abiword -2.8.6

Tags: installation, abiword

Folks, I am totally new to Linux, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 with Cinnamon desktop, I want to install Abiword (an older version) because it's very stable compared with the new one.

I have downloaded the tar file and uncompressed it but I don't know what to do next .

The software centre only has the new unstable version

How can I do this by editing menu? 
Step by step please people I am so new.

Comment: rather than asking how to downgrade, you could ask how to resolve the stability problems, which is probably easier.

Comment: @ImaginaryRobots: in the case of Abiword this question is fair, as we have included unstable SVN releases recently, and there are bugs reported where downgrading is recommended as a workaround (e.g. see [bug #991399](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xserver-xorg-input-synaptics/+bug/991399/comments/9)).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I install a .tar.gz (or .tar.bz2) file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25961/how-do-i-install-a-tar-gz-or-tar-bz2-file)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "editing menu", but you can always download the .deb file from [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/amd64/abiword/2.8.6-0.3ubuntu2) (64bit) or [here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/precise/i386/abiword/2.8.6-0.3ubuntu2) (32bit)